# JSON show only the value without the key

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

**Hi again.**

I have an JSON output in my WebApi controller with entity framework.
Here it's looks like:

```
"Answers":[{"Text":"text text text"},{"Text":"text text text"},{"Text":"text text text"}]}]
```

I want to show it like that:

```
"Answers":["text text text","text text text","text text text"]
```

Here is my Entity Model (answers class):

```
public class Answers
{
    [Key]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    // An Answers related to a Question
    public virtual Question Question { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to convert the array of objects into an array of strings.

You can do that by creating an anonymous type:

```
new { 
    question.Text,
    Answers = question.Answers.Select(a => a.Text)
}
```

Comment: @DanielChernenkov: This create a new object that can be serialized to JSON.